# Missing ')' in formula

Tags: formula, error

I have this formula that says error Missing: ')', but I don't see any mistake.

```
IF(
  AND(
    ISPICKVAL(Case.Type, "Order"),
    ISPICKVAL(Case.Subtype__c, "B2B Leasing"),
    Case.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Order_Case"
  ),
  "test@gmail.com",
  IF(
    AND(
      ISPICKVAL(Case.Type, "Order"),
      ISPICKVAL(Case.Subtype__c, "Support B2B Leasing"),
      Case.RecordType.DeveloperName = "Support"
    ),
    "test2@gmail.com",
    IF(
      ISPICKVAL(Case.Subtype__c, "B2B Leasing"),
      $Setup.Environment_Specific_Parameters__c.Order_Confirmation_Fr om_Email_Address__c,
      $Setup.Environment_Specific_Parameters__c.Customer_Support_From_Email_Address__c
    )
  )
)
```

Do you have any idea?
Thank you

Comment: Please use plain text instead of an image to show the formula. As an image, we can't copy-paste it into a text editor to help you diagnose the problem easier.

Answer (score 1):

You have an extra space:

```
        $Setup.Environment_Specific_Parameters__c.Order_Confirmation_Fr om_Email_Address__c,
```

This is causing the compiler to think you're missing a parantheses.

Comment: Yes, I was blind :) thank you very much!

Comment: @Lukas No problem! It happens to all of us from time to time.